# How to get a "smoothed" wireframe using Freestyle lines?

Tags: rendering, shaders, freestyle

Let's say I have a cylinder. When I turn on smooth shading and auto-smooth, the side edges are smoothed out like this:

[image]

So the question is, can I do that on wireframes? I mean I want to hide all the smoothed edges, leave the outline and sharp edges alone like this:

[image]
(photoshopped)

I guess some eevee shaders could do that but I don't know how.

Comment: Hello :). You might be confusing normals and geometry. Normals can be smoothed, but geometry stays the same.

Comment: Thanks for explaining...I know geometry won't be smoothed. I just want those "smoothed" edges to disappear in viewport or render result.

Comment: @Liuuzaki In the viewport, you can play with the "Wireframe" threshold slider under the overlays menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Freestyle, one of its parameters is 'Crease Angle'.

[image]

If you set that high in Freestyle's general settings, and one of the discriminants for the Line Set is *Edge Type > Crease*, then Freestyle will [pick up edges](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html#edge-types) between faces where the internal angle between them is below the given threshold.

There is a 'Face Smoothness' checkbox for the Crease Angle. If it is unchecked, it will use the angle between face-normals in the underlying geometry. If checked, it will use the normals as interpolated by the smooth shading algorithm...

[image]

...above, with 'Face Smoothness' checked. The left cylinder is flat-shaded, and the right cylinder smooth-shaded, with Autosmooth set to split out its caps.

There is also a *Crease Angle* modifier available for attributes of the Line Style. So you can, for example, vary the color of the line, depending on the angle between the faces it separates:

[image]

You can always render out Freestyle as a separate pass, to composite with other components as you choose.

Answer (score 3):

I've done some research and I found [this nice free, non-photorealistic render engine](https://blendernpr.org/beer/). By using one of the sample materials, I got the following result and it's a *realtime* one!

[image]

---

*In short:*

- Go to https://github.com/bnpr/Malt/releases, download
  `BlenderMalt-[Your OS].zip` and `Shader-Examples.zip`
- Install `BlenderMalt-[Your OS].zip` as an addon
- Unzip `Shader-Examples.zip` to wherever you like
- Set render engine to *Malt*:

  [image]
- Add a new material, select a sample material for "Shader Source".
  (*advanced_line.mesh.glsl* for this case)

  [image]
- Then you can play with these material settings, they are quite self-explanatory

  [image]

Comment: Hi Liuuzaki. Thanks for this answer! Agree with @brockmann. if you could manage to flesh it out, I would appreciate the information, too.

Comment: Cheers for the update. +1. P.S. If you prefer your answer to mine, you can accept it instead!

Comment: Good one! Had no idea this renderer existed :)